# Go Flag Usage Description Contains the Word value

Tags: go

I've defined a custom flag for accepting a slice of strings as such:

```golang
type strSliceFlag []string

func (i *strSliceFlag) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(*i)
}

func (i *strSliceFlag) Set(value string) error {
    *i = append(*i, value)
    return nil
}
```

I then parse it with

```golang
    ...
    var tags strSliceFlag
    flag.Var(&tags, "t", tFlagExpl)
    flag.Parse()
    ...
```

When I build this program, and run it with the help flag: `main -h`, it prints out:

```
Usage of main:
  -t value
        Test explanation
```

My question is, where is the word `value` coming from? I can't find out how to remove it. I think it maybe has something to do with the default value for the flag.

Comment: there is no default value. In any case, I recommend using this package https://github.com/spf13/pflag. It allows you to mix the order of flags and args. It has already array flags. It has methods to set long and short form at once.  And you can influence the printed value of custom flags by implementing a Type method on your types. As well as some other good stuff. I personally think its is much better than the built in flag package.

Comment: @Zombo i figured out it was because I was setting a bool flag, which doesn't have a default value viewable in the usage description. If I set a default on a string flag, I can see that it is shown at the end of the description as `(default "foo")`, which I think is expected behaviour.

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/flag#PrintDefaults for information on how usage is printed.  It describes the handling of bool flags and how to change `value`  to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is the default argument name chosen by [`flag.UnquoteUsage`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#UnquoteUsage) for custom types (rendered via [`flag.(*FlagSet).PrintDefaults`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#FlagSet.PrintDefaults)).

You can override the default with backquotes in your usage text. The backquotes are stripped from usage text. Eg:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

type stringSlice []string

func (s *stringSlice) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(*s)
}

func (s *stringSlice) Set(v string) error {
    *s = append(*s, v)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var s stringSlice
    flag.Var(&s, "foo", "append a foo to the list")
    flag.Var(&s, "foo2", "append a `foo` to the list")
    flag.Parse()
}
```

Running with `-h` shows how the argument name changes:

```
Usage of ./flagusage:
  -foo value
        append a foo to the list
  -foo2 foo
        append a foo to the list
```